# Removing `use strict` via Webpack

Tags: webpack

Is there a way to configure webpack so that it removes all `use strict` statement from the output js?
I'm having issues with IE11 that (incorrectly) complains about `multiple property not allowed in strict mode`. (and I have to support IE11 :()

Comment: Removing `use strict` is not a solution. Removing `multiple property` is.